# Reading from external html source custom objects

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with read from an external html source 
 All I want is to read an custom object in my case 'HSDPA 2100'
But my actual code is read all nfo class from external source.

Piece of External html:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
<tbody><tr>
<th rowspan="8" scope="row">General</th>
<td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">2G Network</a></td>
<td class="nfo">CDMA 800 / 1900 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nfo">GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">3G Network</a></td>
<td class="nfo">HSDPA 2100 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nfo">CDMA2000 1xEV-DO </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="network-bands.php3">4G Network</a></td>
<td class="nfo">LTE 800 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=sim">SIM</a></td>
<td class="nfo">Mini-SIM</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="#" onclick="helpW('h_year.htm');">Announced</a></td>
<td class="nfo">2013, January</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="#" onclick="helpW('h_status.htm');">Status</a></td>
<td class="nfo">Coming soon. Exp. release 2013, February</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table><table cellspacing="0">
<tbody><tr>
<th rowspan="2" scope="row">Body</th>
<td class="ttl"><a href="#" onclick="helpW('h_dimens.htm');">Dimensions</a></td>
<td class="nfo">-</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="#" onclick="helpW('h_weight.htm');">Weight</a></td>
<td class="nfo">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table><table cellspacing="0">
<tbody><tr>
<th rowspan="4" scope="row">Display</th>
<td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=display-type">Type</a></td>
<td class="nfo">TFT capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="#" onclick="helpW('h_dsize.htm');">Size</a></td>
<td class="nfo">1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.9 inches (~373 ppi pixel density)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=multitouch">Multitouch</a></td>
<td class="nfo">Yes</td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td><td class="nfo">- Flux UX UI</td>
```

I am trying using this code:

```
  <?php
  include_once('/simple_html_dom.php');
  $dom = file_get_html("http://www.site.com/pantech_vega_no_6-5268.php");
  // alternatively use str_get_html($html) if you have the html string already...
  foreach ($dom->find('td[class=nfo]') as $node)
{
$result = $node->innertext;
$price = explode(",", $result);
echo $price[0];
} 
?>
```

And I'm receiving this: `CDMA 800 / 1900 GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 HSDPA 2100 CDMA2000 1xEV-DO LTE 800 Mini-SIM2013Coming soon. Exp. r... etc`

Wat i want is `HSDPA 2100` but for other models of phones value could be `HSDPA 1900` or other and `HSPDA` will always be stable and first.

Comment: well, you simply have to compare $node->innertext to "HSDPA 2100" in the foreach loop, or is there some part of the question I'm not getting?

Comment: in this case HSDPA is 2100 but in other cases could have different value, from phone model to other... hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All td have the same class name "nfo" and you loop through all elements so the result you get is as expected.

If the data you want is always located at the third row you can populate an array instead of getting a variable and then get the third value. Like this $result[2]

UPDATED: If HSDPA is always there just check for it.

```
     <?php
      include_once('/simple_html_dom.php');
      $dom = file_get_html("http://www.site.com/pantech_vega_no_6-5268.php");
      // alternatively use str_get_html($html) if you have the html string already...
      foreach ($dom->find('td[class=nfo]') as $node)
    {
    $result = $node->innertext;
if (strpos($result, 'HSDPA') === false)
{
continue;
}
    $price = explode(",", $result);
    echo $price[0];
break;
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: as i mentioned the word `HSDPA` will always be stable and first but it could also be on first row or fourth or other...

Comment: Updated my answer, just check the word HSDPA is there, if not continue and if found break. If there are multiple HSDPA nfo you can remove the break and you'll get all nodes containing th word.